# Accept any name as XML element - JAXB, CXF

Tags: java, xml, wsdl, jaxb, cxf

I have a XML document, element `<elementName>` in it and hierarchy set in WSDL file. Generated class (from the WSDL file) maps everything correctly (CXF does it). But what if I need to accept `<elementName>` with every name? How can I accept any name and have a correct hierarchy? I hope you understand what I'm trying to explain :)

I tried to use `@XmlElement(name="")` and `@XmlElement(name="*")`, but that didn't work.

**UPDATE:**

```
@XmlAnyElement
protected Container c;
```

And I want to map every element in the same level in XML on it.

To be specific i want these two examples to be mapped into the same class (Container.class as above):

```
... XML hierarchy ...
    <element>
        ... XML content ...
    </element>
```

or

```
... XML hierarchy ...
    <elementWithUglyNameaodsafh>
        ... same XML content as above...
    </elementWithUglyNameaodsafh>
```

Comment: you want jaxb to identify that the content matches Container or you want that every *uglyElement* will be Container?

Comment: See my update, is this a suitable solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use @XmlAnyElement see information here:
http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_6_2_7_6-Collecting-Unspecified-Elements-XmlAnyElement.html#Collecting%20Unspecified%20Elements:%20XmlAnyElement

for example:

```
 public class ZooType {
    protected List<Element> animals;
    public ZooType(){
    }

    @XmlAnyElement
    public List<Element> getAnimals(){
        if( animals == null ) animals = new ArrayList<Element>();
        return animals;   
    }
    public void setAnimals( List value ){
        animals = value;
    }
}
```

you can later extract the element name and value:

```
for( Element el: doc.getZoo().getAnimals() ){
    System.out.println( el.getNodeName() + "->" +
                        el.getTextContent() );
}
```

**EDIT**:

as a response to the update in the question I can offer a workaround solution.

I am sorry, I have never programmed XML, so there is probably a better way to do the element wrapping and replacement.

The bottom line is: use @XmlAnyElement to get the node... and marshal it to your Container  (whihc also have @XmlRootElement annotation)

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

public Container c;

@XmlAnyElement
public void setElements(Element e) throws JAXBException, ParserConfigurationException {
    Document d = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
    Element container = d.createElement("container");
    d.appendChild(container);
    Node node = d.adoptNode(e.getFirstChild());
    container.appendChild(node);
    c = (Container) JAXBContext.newInstance(Container.class).createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(d);
}

public Element getElements() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
}
```

off-course, this code is **ugly** and **not efficient**. I would refactor it before commit.

Comment: If I use this, I get this error: `Unmarshalling Error: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to ....`. How can I cast this to my class?

Comment: @ekeren: I did that. But I have a property and i want to map `<asdasda>` or `<element>` or `<xyz>` or other name in the same level in XML on it. It just doesn't work...

Comment: @Tom: I am not sure I fully understand your problem, can you edit your question with the code?

Comment: If you add lax=true to @XmlAnyElement you will get object content assuming there is a domain class with a compatible root element.  For more info check out:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html

Comment: Your solution works. I found that `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` can be used for creating own (un)marshalling class. Thanks a lot